# Joint density function problem with integration

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

So the question is: $f(x,y)= (2/81)x^3$ for $0\leq x \leq3, 0 \leq y \leq 2$ and $0$ otherwise. Find the probability that (x,y) satisfies $x+y \leq 3$. My thought on this question is to find the intersection between f(x,y) and $y=-x+3$. And they intersect at $x=2.577$. Then I went to integrate two parts: $0-2.577$ under equation $f(x,y)$ with respect to dx and $2.577-3$ under $y=-x+3$ with respect to dx.

However, the answer appears to be incorrect. What is wrong with my thought process here?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math stack exchange!  Please spend a few minutes here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the wrong track.  You have a joint probability density, so the graph is 3D.  Probability is represented by volume.  The condition $x+y \leq 3$ is a constraint on the domain; it is telling you where to integrate.  Since the full domain is $[0,3]\times [0,2]$, you want to do a double integral over the region where $y$ ranges over $0$ to $2$ and $x$ ranges from $0$ to $3-y$.
$$\int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{3-y} \frac{2}{81} x^3 dx dy$$
Draw the region in the x-y plane if this is unclear, or you can integrate in the other order but then you have to split it into 0-1 and 1-3 for the outer integral.